# fetch Array data based on string value

Tags: javascript, lodash

```
const a='Piechart'
const b=[ {graph:"Piechart",value: 1},{graph:"Stackedbarchart",value: 1}]
```

I am comparing a with b and need to get output as value i.e 1 in this case

Comment: It is always good to provide a code to see what you have tried so far...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply do this with Javascript [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) method

```
const a='Piechart'
const b=[ {graph:"Piechart",value: 1},{graph:"Stackedbarchart",value: 1}]

const res = b.find(obj => obj.graph === a);
if(res) {
   console.log(res.value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**ES6**

This will be helpful to get an array of all items in `b` that matches `a` (in case you could have more than 1 items with that name).

```
const filtered = b.filter( value => value.graph === a);
```

Since you have only one, then filtered[0] is what you need. Otherwise you can loop through filtered and get the `value` of every item that matches your requirement.

```
filtered[0].value // 1
```